# Mysql create trigger that insert n time depending on field value

Tags: mysql, triggers, duplicates

i would like to create a trigger function.

When i'm inserting a new row in T1 , i would like a trigger function that will insert n times in another table depending on a field value.

Exemple :

```
T1
ID : 1
Quantity : 5
```

When this row is inserted, my trigger function will be called and will add 5 times a new row in my table T2.

Maybe you could just help me to create a select that will automaticly return me 5 rows... I don't know something like :

```
Select * FROM t1
GROUP by ID, Quantity - 1
```

I already saw something like that but in postgres to count the consecutive value... but i cant use With function in mysql and i don't know where to start.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10356338/3612883

Thank you for your help.