# SQL query to select 3 consecutive years between records

Tags: mysql

I have a database full of all sorts of records regarding baseball teams and their players. I need to write a query that shows the names of any player who has played for the teamID "MON" three consecutive years. I've already written a query that gives me the table below, showing the years they played for that team.

| nameFirst | nameLast| Year  |
+-----------+---------+-------+
| Santo     | Alcala  | 1977  |
| Santo     | Alcala  | 1978  |
| Santo     | Alcala  | 1979  |
| Scott     | Aldred  | 1993  |

I'm too lazy to enter any more records in the table, but this should be plenty to understand the situation. The actual table in my DB has thousands of records. So the query I need would return one record for Santo Alcala since he played three consecutive years for the MON team. The above table only shows players who played for MON, I already wrote a query that excludes all players who played for teams other than MON.

The desired output of the query would be a record such as:

| nameFirst | nameLast|
+--------------+---------+
| Santo     | Alcala  |

If a player played for more than 3 consecutive years on the team, they would also be shown in the results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding rows with consecutive increase in the values of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354506/finding-rows-with-consecutive-increase-in-the-values-of-a-column)

Comment: They are similar questions, but that one seems a bit more complicated that the scenario my question presents.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like the below?

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE PLAYER (
ID INT,  
FIRST VARCHAR(25),
LAST VARCHAR(25),
YEAR INT  
);
```

**INSERTS**

```
INSERT INTO PLAYER (ID, FIRST, LAST, YEAR) VALUES (1, "Santo", "Alcala", 1977);
INSERT INTO PLAYER (ID, FIRST, LAST, YEAR) VALUES (2, "Santo", "Alcala", 1978);
INSERT INTO PLAYER (ID, FIRST, LAST, YEAR) VALUES (3, "Santo", "Alcala", 1979);
INSERT INTO PLAYER (ID, FIRST, LAST, YEAR) VALUES (4, "Santo", "Alcala", 1980);
INSERT INTO PLAYER (ID, FIRST, LAST, YEAR) VALUES (5, "Santo", "Aldred", 1993);
INSERT INTO PLAYER (ID, FIRST, LAST, YEAR) VALUES (6, "Santo", "Aldred", 1994);
INSERT INTO PLAYER (ID, FIRST, LAST, YEAR) VALUES (7, "Santo", "Royal",  1994);
```

**Query**

```
select DISTINCT(FIRST), LAST from player where ID 
IN (select p1.ID from player p1 inner join player p2 
    on p1.year = p2.year+1 and p1.first = p2.first and p2.last = p1.last);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
FIRST   LAST
Santo   Alcala
Santo   Aldred
```

**SQL FIDDLE** 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5c1c4/1

Comment: It is returning the value for 2 consecutive years as well which should not. What is the condition for 3 consecutive years?

Comment: @ojuskulkarni You would need to add another `AND` clause to the subquery with the condition `p1.year = p2.year+2`