# Oracle sql or pl/sql: Compute based on previous row values and on date column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I found lot of solution related to my issue on Python technology but couldn't find much on Oracle SQL or PL/SQL solution. So trying it on Oracle SQL with Oracle Application Express.

I have db table that has below sample stock data for 8 days. New records are inserted every day after the market closes. I have query to find the stocks that have consecutive increase/decrease in price. Now I would like to add one more column where I can see a Pattern called bullish or bearish based on the present date and previous date values.

```
+-------+------------+--------+-------+-------+--------+--------+
| Stock |   Cdate    |  Open  | High  |  Low  | Close  | Volume |
+-------+------------+--------+-------+-------+--------+--------+
| XYZ   | 01-01-2021 |     40 |  40.5 |  38.5 |   38.8 |  83057 |
| XYZ   | 02-01-2021 |   39.2 |  39.2 |  37.2 |   37.8 | 181814 |
| XYZ   | 03-01-2021 |     38 |  38.5 |  36.5 |     37 | 117378 |
| XYZ   | 04-01-2021 |     36 |  36.1 |  35.6 |   35.7 |  93737 |
| XYZ   | 05-01-2021 |  35.35 |  36.8 |  35.1 |   36.6 | 169106 |
| XYZ   | 06-01-2021 |   36.5 |  38.5 |  36.5 |     38 | 123179 |
| XYZ   | 07-01-2021 |   37.5 |  39.5 |  37.3 |   39.4 | 282986 |
| XYZ   | 08-01-2021 |     39 |  40.5 |  38.5 |     40 | 117437 |
|       |            |        |       |       |        |        |
| DDD   | 01-01-2021 | 135.35 | 136.8 | 135.1 |  136.6 |  16454 |
| DDD   | 02-01-2021 |  136.5 | 138.5 | 136.5 |    138 | 281461 |
| DDD   | 03-01-2021 |  137.5 | 139.5 | 137.3 |  139.4 |  77334 |
| DDD   | 04-01-2021 |    139 | 140.5 | 138.5 |    140 | 321684 |
| DDD   | 05-01-2021 |  139.7 | 139.8 | 139.3 |  139.4 | 873009 |
| DDD   | 06-01-2021 |  139.2 | 139.2 | 137.2 |  137.8 |  62522 |
| DDD   | 07-01-2021 |    138 | 138.5 | 136.5 |    137 | 114826 |
| DDD   | 08-01-2021 |  136.6 | 136.8 | 135.1 | 135.35 |  27317 |
+-------+------------+--------+-------+-------+--------+--------+
```

This is how the chart looks for stock XYZ:
[image]

On 5th Jan 2021, the trend changed and I would like to add new column saying "Bullish" based on the formula:

```
O1 > C1 and C > O and C > H1 and O < L1
```

where,

```
O1 = Previous day Open price  
C1 = Previous day Close price  
C  = Today's Close price  
O  = Today's Open price  
H1 = Previous day High price  
L1 = Previous day Low price
```

Expected output will be a new column saying "Bullish" under column Pattern:

```
+-------+------------+-------+------+------+-------+--------+---------+
| Stock |   Cdate    | Open  | High | Low  | Close | Volume | Pattern |
+-------+------------+-------+------+------+-------+--------+---------+
| XYZ   | 01-01-2021 |    40 | 40.5 | 38.5 |  38.8 |  83057 |         |
| XYZ   | 02-01-2021 |  39.2 | 39.2 | 37.2 |  37.8 | 181814 |         |
| XYZ   | 03-01-2021 |    38 | 38.5 | 36.5 |    37 | 117378 |         |
| XYZ   | 04-01-2021 |    36 | 36.1 | 35.6 |  35.7 |  93737 |         |
| XYZ   | 05-01-2021 | 35.35 | 36.8 | 35.1 |  36.6 | 169106 | Bullish |
| XYZ   | 06-01-2021 |  36.5 | 38.5 | 36.5 |    38 | 123179 |         |
| XYZ   | 07-01-2021 |  37.5 | 39.5 | 37.3 |  39.4 | 282986 |         |
| XYZ   | 08-01-2021 |    39 | 40.5 | 38.5 |    40 | 117437 |         |
+-------+------------+-------+------+------+-------+--------+---------+
```

I searched over the internet for solution and the closest I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354506/finding-rows-with-consecutive-increase-in-the-values-of-a-column). I modified the query a bit but was not able to add formula or any other new columns. Below is the query I tried:

```
WITH StockRow AS (SELECT stock, close, cdate,
                         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY stock
                                           ORDER BY cdate) rn
                  FROM sampletable where volume > 200000),

     RunGroup AS (SELECT Base.stock, Base.cdate, base.close,
                         MAX(Restart.rn) OVER(PARTITION BY Base.stock
                                              ORDER BY Base.cdate) groupingId
                  FROM StockRow Base
                  LEFT JOIN StockRow Restart
                         ON Restart.stock = Base.stock
                            AND Restart.rn = Base.rn - 1
                            AND Restart.CLOSE < Base.CLOSE)

SELECT stock, 
       COUNT(*) AS consecutiveCount, 
       MIN(cdate) AS startDate, MAX(cdate) AS endDate, min(close) as latestclose
FROM RunGroup
GROUP BY stock, groupingId
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
and MAX(cdate) = (select max(cdate) from sampletable)
ORDER BY CONSECUTIVECOUNT desc, stock, startDate
```

Similarly for stock, "DDD" below is how chart looks and the final data:

[image: Stock DDD, bearish]

On 5th Jan 2021, the trend changed and I would like to add new column saying "Bearish" based on the formula:

```
C < O and C < C1 and O < C1 and O1 < C1 and C > O1 and O < C1
```

where,

```
O1 = Previous day Open price  
C1 = Previous day Close price  
C = Today's Close price  
O = Today's Open price  


+-------+------------+--------+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------+
| Stock |   Cdate    |  Open  | High  |  Low  | Close  | Volume | Pattern |
+-------+------------+--------+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------+
| XYZ   | 01-01-2021 |     40 |  40.5 |  38.5 |   38.8 |  83057 |         |
| XYZ   | 02-01-2021 |   39.2 |  39.2 |  37.2 |   37.8 | 181814 |         |
| XYZ   | 03-01-2021 |     38 |  38.5 |  36.5 |     37 | 117378 |         |
| XYZ   | 04-01-2021 |     36 |  36.1 |  35.6 |   35.7 |  93737 |         |
| XYZ   | 05-01-2021 |  35.35 |  36.8 |  35.1 |   36.6 | 169106 | Bullish |
| XYZ   | 06-01-2021 |   36.5 |  38.5 |  36.5 |     38 | 123179 |         |
| XYZ   | 07-01-2021 |   37.5 |  39.5 |  37.3 |   39.4 | 282986 |         |
| XYZ   | 08-01-2021 |     39 |  40.5 |  38.5 |     40 | 117437 |         |
|       |            |        |       |       |        |        |         |
| DDD   | 01-01-2021 | 135.35 | 136.8 | 135.1 |  136.6 |  16454 |         |
| DDD   | 02-01-2021 |  136.5 | 138.5 | 136.5 |    138 | 281461 |         |
| DDD   | 03-01-2021 |  137.5 | 139.5 | 137.3 |  139.4 |  77334 |         |
| DDD   | 04-01-2021 |    139 | 140.5 | 138.5 |    140 | 321684 |         |
| DDD   | 05-01-2021 |  139.7 | 139.8 | 139.3 |  139.4 | 873009 | Bearish |
| DDD   | 06-01-2021 |  139.2 | 139.2 | 137.2 |  137.8 |  62522 |         |
| DDD   | 07-01-2021 |    138 | 138.5 | 136.5 |    137 | 114826 |         |
| DDD   | 08-01-2021 |  136.6 | 136.8 | 135.1 | 135.35 |  27317 |         |
+-------+------------+--------+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------+
```

Appreciate any help on this.

Update: Sorry if I asking too much. This is what I am trying to achieve.
In simple words, I would like to identify areas highlighted in yellow in below screenshots only if it is in upmove/uptrend or downmove/downtrend.

**Stock XYZ, bullish on 05-01-2021**
[image]

**Stock DDD, bearish on 05-01-2021**
[image]

Thanks,
Richa

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Oracle 12c, you can do it using `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY stock
  ORDER     BY cdate
  MEASURES
    CLASSIFIER() AS pttrn
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (bullish|bearish|other)
  DEFINE
    bullish AS  PREV(open) > PREV(close)
            AND Close > Open
            AND Close > PREV(High)
            AND Open  < PREV(Low),
    bearish AS  Close < Open
            AND Close < PREV(Close)
            AND Open  < PREV(Close)
            AND PREV(Open) < PREV(Close)
            AND Close > PREV(Open)
            AND Open  < PREV(Close)
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Stock, Cdate, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume ) AS
SELECT 'XYZ', DATE '2021-01-01',  40.00,  40.50,  38.50,  38.80,  83057 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'XYZ', DATE '2021-01-02',  39.20,  39.20,  37.20,  37.80, 181814 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'XYZ', DATE '2021-01-03',  38.00,  38.50,  36.50,  37.00, 117378 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'XYZ', DATE '2021-01-04',  36.00,  36.10,  35.60,  35.70,  93737 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'XYZ', DATE '2021-01-05',  35.35,  36.80,  35.10,  36.60, 169106 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'XYZ', DATE '2021-01-06',  36.50,  38.50,  36.50,  38.00, 123179 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'XYZ', DATE '2021-01-07',  37.50,  39.50,  37.30,  39.40, 282986 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'XYZ', DATE '2021-01-08',  39.00,  40.50,  38.50,  40.00, 117437 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DDD', DATE '2021-01-01', 135.35, 136.80, 135.10, 136.60,  16454 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DDD', DATE '2021-01-02', 136.50, 138.50, 136.50, 138.00, 281461 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DDD', DATE '2021-01-03', 137.50, 139.50, 137.30, 139.40,  77334 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DDD', DATE '2021-01-04', 139.00, 140.50, 138.50, 140.00, 321684 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DDD', DATE '2021-01-05', 139.70, 139.80, 139.30, 139.40, 873009 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DDD', DATE '2021-01-06', 139.20, 139.20, 137.20, 137.80,  62522 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DDD', DATE '2021-01-07', 138.00, 138.50, 136.50, 137.00, 114826 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DDD', DATE '2021-01-08', 136.60, 136.80, 135.10, 135.35,  27317 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | STOCK | CDATE | PTTRN | OPEN | HIGH | LOW | CLOSE | VOLUME |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | DDD | 01-JAN-21 | OTHER | 135.35 | 136.8 | 135.1 | 136.6 | 16454 |
> | DDD | 02-JAN-21 | OTHER | 136.5 | 138.5 | 136.5 | 138 | 281461 |
> | DDD | 03-JAN-21 | OTHER | 137.5 | 139.5 | 137.3 | 139.4 | 77334 |
> | DDD | 04-JAN-21 | OTHER | 139 | 140.5 | 138.5 | 140 | 321684 |
> | DDD | 05-JAN-21 | BEARISH | 139.7 | 139.8 | 139.3 | 139.4 | 873009 |
> | DDD | 06-JAN-21 | OTHER | 139.2 | 139.2 | 137.2 | 137.8 | 62522 |
> | DDD | 07-JAN-21 | OTHER | 138 | 138.5 | 136.5 | 137 | 114826 |
> | DDD | 08-JAN-21 | OTHER | 136.6 | 136.8 | 135.1 | 135.35 | 27317 |
> | XYZ | 01-JAN-21 | OTHER | 40 | 40.5 | 38.5 | 38.8 | 83057 |
> | XYZ | 02-JAN-21 | OTHER | 39.2 | 39.2 | 37.2 | 37.8 | 181814 |
> | XYZ | 03-JAN-21 | OTHER | 38 | 38.5 | 36.5 | 37 | 117378 |
> | XYZ | 04-JAN-21 | OTHER | 36 | 36.1 | 35.6 | 35.7 | 93737 |
> | XYZ | 05-JAN-21 | BULLISH | 35.35 | 36.8 | 35.1 | 36.6 | 169106 |
> | XYZ | 06-JAN-21 | OTHER | 36.5 | 38.5 | 36.5 | 38 | 123179 |
> | XYZ | 07-JAN-21 | OTHER | 37.5 | 39.5 | 37.3 | 39.4 | 282986 |
> | XYZ | 08-JAN-21 | OTHER | 39 | 40.5 | 38.5 | 40 | 117437 |

---

You could also use the `LAG` analytic function (which was available before Oracle 12):

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       CASE
       WHEN LAG(open) OVER (PARTITION BY stock ORDER BY cdate)
            > LAG(close) OVER (PARTITION BY stock ORDER BY cdate)
       AND  Close > Open
       AND  Close > LAG(high) OVER (PARTITION BY stock ORDER BY cdate)
       AND  Open  < LAG(low) OVER (PARTITION BY stock ORDER BY cdate)
       THEN 'BULLISH'
       WHEN Close < Open
       AND  Close < LAG(close) OVER (PARTITION BY stock ORDER BY cdate)
       AND  Open  < LAG(close) OVER (PARTITION BY stock ORDER BY cdate)
       AND  LAG(open) OVER (PARTITION BY stock ORDER BY cdate)
            < LAG(close) OVER (PARTITION BY stock ORDER BY cdate)
       AND  Close > LAG(open) OVER (PARTITION BY stock ORDER BY cdate)
       AND  Open  < LAG(close) OVER (PARTITION BY stock ORDER BY cdate)
       THEN 'BEARISH'
       ELSE 'OTHER'
       END AS pttrn
FROM   table_name t
```

(Which gives similar output.)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=388c411d3c001ea98769e4b237a56f10)*

---

## Update: tracking UP and DOWN:

Again, this is what `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` is for:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY stock
  ORDER     BY cdate
  MEASURES
    CLASSIFIER() AS pttrn
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (^initial_value|bullish|bearish|up|down|other)
  DEFINE
    bullish AS  PREV(open) > PREV(close)
            AND Close > Open
            AND Close > PREV(High)
            AND Open  < PREV(Low),
    bearish AS  Close < Open
            AND Close < PREV(Close)
            AND Open  < PREV(Close)
            AND PREV(Open) < PREV(Close)
            AND Close > PREV(Open)
            AND Open  < PREV(Close),
    up      AS  close > PREV(close)
            AND open  > PREV(open),
    down    AS  close < PREV(close)
            AND open  < PREV(open)
)
```

But you can do the same with `LAG`:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       CASE
       WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY stock ORDER BY cdate) = 1
       THEN 'INITIAL_VALUE'
       WHEN LAG(open) OVER (PARTITION BY stock ORDER BY cdate)
            > LAG(close) OVER (PARTITION BY stock ORDER BY cdate)
       AND  Close > Open
       AND  Close > LAG(high) OVER (PARTITION BY stock ORDER BY cdate)
       AND  Open  < LAG(low) OVER (PARTITION BY stock ORDER BY cdate)
       THEN 'BULLISH'
       WHEN Close < Open
       AND  Close < LAG(close) OVER (PARTITION BY stock ORDER BY cdate)
       AND  Open  < LAG(close) OVER (PARTITION BY stock ORDER BY cdate)
       AND  LAG(open) OVER (PARTITION BY stock ORDER BY cdate)
            < LAG(close) OVER (PARTITION BY stock ORDER BY cdate)
       AND  Close > LAG(open) OVER (PARTITION BY stock ORDER BY cdate)
       AND  Open  < LAG(close) OVER (PARTITION BY stock ORDER BY cdate)
       THEN 'BEARISH'
       WHEN Close > LAG(Close) OVER (PARTITION BY stock ORDER BY cdate)
       AND  Open  > LAG(Open) OVER (PARTITION BY stock ORDER BY cdate)
       THEN 'UP'
       WHEN Close < LAG(Close) OVER (PARTITION BY stock ORDER BY cdate)
       AND  Open  < LAG(Open) OVER (PARTITION BY stock ORDER BY cdate)
       THEN 'DOWN'
       ELSE 'OTHER'
       END AS pttrn
FROM   table_name t
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2a4b643d17f9d12fdce3df670a7203b6)*

Comment: Thank you @MT0 for quick response. I really appreciate your help. Soory if my question was not clear enough. With the query you provided, I am getting bullish or bearish but I want to use it in combination with query which I posted in OP, so that I can identify if in uptrend or in downtrend. As of now this is giving lot of false signals. Is it possible to combine this query with yours?
WITH StockRow AS (SELECT stock, close, cdate,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY stock
ORDER BY cdate) rn
FROM sampletable where volume > 200000),
RunGroup AS (SELECT Base.stock, Base.cdate...

Comment: @Richa Your query returns zero rows [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3bd782acc414f0a8a2213953a02cb86c) so I am not sure what it is intended to do and it is too complicated to try to reverse engineer it. If you want to identify up and down trends then just use more rules in `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` or other `LAG` comparisons; I've update the answer with examples. However, my original queries gave the expected output to your original question. If the original question was not as intended then please don't bait and switch and change the question; ask a new, clearer question.

Comment: Sure let me do that @MT0. It's better for me to post new question rather than to confuse myself and everyone else. Good suggestion. Thank you for your valuable time and help. I appreciate it. I have marked your answer as correct