# Oracle SQL or PL/SQL: How to identify candlestick pattern only in end of uptrend or downtrend and set a flag in column?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

*This question and related answers will be for educational or learning purpose only.*

This question is much different from my other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69435319/oracle-sql-or-pl-sql-compute-based-on-previous-row-values-and-on-date-column/69435871?noredirect=1#comment122732933_69435871) and is not duplicate. Since it was creating confusion and as suggested by @MT0, I am posting this as a new question here.

I have below table, where I upload stock data on daily basis.

```
/* CREATE TABLE */
CREATE TABLE RAW_SOURCE(
  Stock  VARCHAR(100),
  Close_Date DATE,
  Open   NUMBER,
  High   NUMBER,
  Low    NUMBER,
  Close  NUMBER,
  Volume NUMBER
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 1 */
INSERT INTO RAW_SOURCE(Stock, Close_Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume)
VALUES
(
'XYZ', '01/01/2021', 40, 40.5, 38.5, 38.8, 83057
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 2 */
INSERT INTO RAW_SOURCE(Stock, Close_Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume)
VALUES
(
'XYZ', '02/01/2021', 39.2, 39.2, 37.2, 37.8, 181814
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 3 */
INSERT INTO RAW_SOURCE(Stock, Close_Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume)
VALUES
(
'XYZ', '03/01/2021', 38, 38.5, 36.5, 37, 117378
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 4 */
INSERT INTO RAW_SOURCE(Stock, Close_Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume)
VALUES
(
'XYZ', '04/01/2021', 36.5, 36.6, 35.6, 35.7, 93737
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 5 */
INSERT INTO RAW_SOURCE(Stock, Close_Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume)
VALUES
(
'XYZ', '05/01/2021', 35.35, 36.8, 35.1, 36.7, 169106
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 6 */
INSERT INTO RAW_SOURCE(Stock, Close_Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume)
VALUES
(
'XYZ', '06/01/2021', 36.5, 38.5, 36.5, 38, 123179
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 7 */
INSERT INTO RAW_SOURCE(Stock, Close_Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume)
VALUES
(
'XYZ', '07/01/2021', 37.5, 39.5, 37.3, 39.4, 282986
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 8 */
INSERT INTO RAW_SOURCE(Stock, Close_Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume)
VALUES
(
'XYZ', '08/01/2021', 39, 40.5, 38.5, 40, 117437
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 9 */
INSERT INTO RAW_SOURCE(Stock, Close_Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume)
VALUES
(
'XYZ', '09/01/2021', 39.7, 39.8, 39.3, 39.4, 873009
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 10 */
INSERT INTO RAW_SOURCE(Stock, Close_Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume)
VALUES
(
'XYZ', '10/01/2021', 39.2, 39.2, 37.2, 37.8, 62522
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 11 */
INSERT INTO RAW_SOURCE(Stock, Close_Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume)
VALUES
(
'XYZ', '11/01/2021', 38, 38.5, 36.5, 37, 114826
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 12 */
INSERT INTO RAW_SOURCE(Stock, Close_Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume)
VALUES
(
'XYZ', '12/01/2021', 36.5, 37.9, 36.3, 37.8, 281461
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 13 */
INSERT INTO RAW_SOURCE(Stock, Close_Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume)
VALUES
(
'XYZ', '13/01/2021', 37.5, 39.5, 37.3, 39.4, 77334
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 14 */
INSERT INTO RAW_SOURCE(Stock, Close_Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume)
VALUES
(
'XYZ', '14/01/2021', 39, 40.5, 38.5, 40, 321684
);
```

Below is the sample data for one stock "XYZ":

```
+-------+------------+-------+------+------+-------+--------+
| Stock | Close Date | Open  | High | Low  | Close | Volume |
+-------+------------+-------+------+------+-------+--------+
| XYZ   | 01-01-2021 |    40 | 40.5 | 38.5 |  38.8 |  83057 |
| XYZ   | 02-01-2021 |  39.2 | 39.2 | 37.2 |  37.8 | 181814 |
| XYZ   | 03-01-2021 |    38 | 38.5 | 36.5 |    37 | 117378 |
| XYZ   | 04-01-2021 |  36.5 | 36.6 | 35.6 |  35.7 |  93737 |
| XYZ   | 05-01-2021 | 35.35 | 36.8 | 35.1 |  36.7 | 169106 |
| XYZ   | 06-01-2021 |  36.5 | 38.5 | 36.5 |    38 | 123179 |
| XYZ   | 07-01-2021 |  37.5 | 39.5 | 37.3 |  39.4 | 282986 |
| XYZ   | 08-01-2021 |    39 | 40.5 | 38.5 |    40 | 117437 |
| XYZ   | 09-01-2021 |  39.7 | 39.8 | 39.3 |  39.4 | 873009 |
| XYZ   | 10-01-2021 |  39.2 | 39.2 | 37.2 |  37.8 |  62522 |
| XYZ   | 11-01-2021 |    38 | 38.5 | 36.5 |    37 | 114826 |
| XYZ   | 12-01-2021 |  36.5 | 37.9 | 36.3 |  37.8 | 281461 |
| XYZ   | 13-01-2021 |  37.5 | 39.5 | 37.3 |  39.4 |  77334 |
| XYZ   | 14-01-2021 |    39 | 40.5 | 38.5 |    40 | 321684 |
+-------+------------+-------+------+------+-------+--------+
```

Over the period of time, there will be more than thousands of records for each stock symbol and I would like to identify candlestick pattern only at the top of upmove/uptrend or at the bottom of downmove/downtrend but NOT in sideways (Since this will be false positive). Below is the sample screeshot:

[image]

Assuming today is ***12th Jan 2021***, below is the expected output:

```
+-------+-------------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------+---------------+
| Stock | Consecutive Count | Start Date |  End Date  | Latest Close | Volume |    Pattern    |
+-------+-------------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------+---------------+
| XYZ   |                 3 | 09-01-2021 | 12-01-2021 |         37.8 | 281461 | Piercing Line |
+-------+-------------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------+---------------+
```

Since the source table will have many other stocks, would like to show results on 12th Jan 2021 for other stocks as well if there is any pattern identified.
I feel this is quite challenging and complex logic. Hence seeking help here. Thanks in advance.

**Update:** Thank you @JustinCave
Here's the formula for calculation:
For **Bullish Engulfing**:

```
O1 > C1 and C > O and C > H1 and O < L1
where,

O1 = Previous day Open price  
C1 = Previous day Close price  
C  = Today's Close price  
O  = Today's Open price  
H1 = Previous day High price  
L1 = Previous day Low price
```

For **Bearish Harami**:

```
(O1 < C1) and (O > C) and (O < C1) and (C > O1) and (H < H1) and (L > L1)
where,
    O1 = Previous day Open price  
    C1 = Previous day Close price  
    C  = Today's Close price  
    O  = Today's Open price  
    H1 = Previous day High price  
    L1 = Previous day Low price 
    H  = Today's High price  
    L  = Today's Low price
```

For **Piercing Line**:

```
(O < C) and (O1 > C1) and (C > (C1 + O1)/2) and (O < C1) and (C < O1)
    where,
        O1 = Previous day Open price  
        C1 = Previous day Close price  
        C  = Today's Close price  
        O  = Today's Open price
```

Comment: This seems like a problem which can be solved via `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`.  Take a look at this Oracle Deep Dive explaining how to use it (The example they use is actually stock patterns). ([Link](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/bi-datawarehousing/mr-deep-dive-3769287.pdf))

Comment: If you don't want to adapt the `match_recognize` logic that @MT0 provided you in your other question, you'd at least need to specify the exact logic you want to use.  What constitutes a "Piercing Line" for example rather than a "Bullish Engulfing"?

Comment: Thank you @Del. I am going thru the link.

Comment: Thank you @JustinCave. I have updated the formula in OP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Patterns in `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` work in a similar fashion to regular expressions; you want something like:

*(Note: your `PIERCING_LINE` formula does not give the expected output so I have assumed you want `C > (C1 + O1)/2` rather than `C > C1 + (O1/2)`.)*

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   raw_source
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY stock
  ORDER BY Close_Date
  MEASURES
    CLASSIFIER() AS pttrn
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (
    ^initial_value
    |
    down+ (bullish_engulfing | piercing_line | $)
    |
    up+ (bearish_harami | $)
    |
    other
  )
  DEFINE
    down AS
          PREV(open) > open
      AND PREV(close) > close
      AND PREV(open) > PREV(close)
      AND open > close,
    up AS
          PREV(open) < open
      AND PREV(close) < close
      AND PREV(open) < PREV(close)
      AND open < close,
    bullish_engulfing AS
      -- O1 > C1 and C > O and C > H1 and O < L1
          PREV(open) > PREV(close)
      AND close > open
      AND close > PREV(high)
      AND open  < PREV(low),
    bearish_harami AS
      -- O1 < C1 and O > C and O < C1 and C > O1 and H < H1 and L > L1
          PREV(open) < PREV(close)
      AND open > close
      AND open < PREV(close)
      AND close > PREV(open)
      AND high < PREV(high)
      AND low > PREV(low),
    piercing_line AS
      -- O < C and O1 > C1 and C > (C1 + O1)/2 and O < C1 and C < O1
          open < close
      AND PREV(open) > PREV(close)
      AND close > (PREV(close) + PREV(open))/2
      AND open < PREV(close)
      AND close < PREV(open)
)
```

Which outputs:

> | STOCK | CLOSE_DATE | PTTRN | OPEN | HIGH | LOW | CLOSE | VOLUME |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | XYZ | 01/01/2021 | INITIAL_VALUE | 40 | 40.5 | 38.5 | 38.8 | 83057 |
> | XYZ | 02/01/2021 | DOWN | 39.2 | 39.2 | 37.2 | 37.8 | 181814 |
> | XYZ | 03/01/2021 | DOWN | 38 | 38.5 | 36.5 | 37 | 117378 |
> | XYZ | 04/01/2021 | DOWN | 36.5 | 36.6 | 35.6 | 35.7 | 93737 |
> | XYZ | 05/01/2021 | BULLISH_ENGULFING | 35.35 | 36.8 | 35.1 | 36.7 | 169106 |
> | XYZ | 06/01/2021 | UP | 36.5 | 38.5 | 36.5 | 38 | 123179 |
> | XYZ | 07/01/2021 | UP | 37.5 | 39.5 | 37.3 | 39.4 | 282986 |
> | XYZ | 08/01/2021 | UP | 39 | 40.5 | 38.5 | 40 | 117437 |
> | XYZ | 09/01/2021 | BEARISH_HARAMI | 39.7 | 39.8 | 39.3 | 39.4 | 873009 |
> | XYZ | 10/01/2021 | DOWN | 39.2 | 39.2 | 37.2 | 37.8 | 62522 |
> | XYZ | 11/01/2021 | DOWN | 38 | 38.5 | 36.5 | 37 | 114826 |
> | XYZ | 12/01/2021 | PIERCING_LINE | 36.5 | 37.9 | 36.3 | 37.8 | 281461 |
> | XYZ | 13/01/2021 | UP | 37.5 | 39.5 | 37.3 | 39.4 | 77334 |
> | XYZ | 14/01/2021 | UP | 39 | 40.5 | 38.5 | 40 | 321684 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=774f5899d9849becf1586ce6f58b548d)*

Comment: Thank you so much @MT0. It is working fine if I run this query in SQL commands but getting issue in front end of Oracle Apex. Give error "ORA-00911: invalid character". I think it is because of carat and dollar symbol. May I know if there's a fix for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Richa Remove those characters [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=431de13a11ba00c0caabafd8967cfdac) and see if it works in Apex. Apex is an application that I do not use so I cannot advise you on specific settings for it.

Comment: Thank you @MT0. No problem. I feel issue is occurring at this line   ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (
    down+ (bullish_engulfing | piercing_line) | up+ bearish_harami? | other
  )
I will read documentation and see if I can fix it. Thank you again for your kind help and time.

Comment: Hi @MT0, now I know how to add latest day close and previous day close. May I know how to add below formula:
4 days ago CLOSE less than 4 days ago OPEN
and
3 days ago CLOSE less than 3 days ago OPEN
and
2 days ago CLOSE less than 2 days ago OPEN

Comment: `close < LAG(open, 4) OVER (PARTITION BY stock ORDER BY close_date)` for the first one and I'm sure you can adapt it to the second and third ... you can probably do it with `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` if you have a pattern that is 4-days wide but there is not enough context on how you would match the intervening days to be able to give that answer.

Comment: I am trying it. Thank you for the help @MT0. I posted sample data that I created on my own for simplicity purpose. If I posted actual data, it would be at least 100 rows and could have created unnecessary confusion. So kept it minimal. Now that you MT0 and JustinCave helped me, I am trying to go a step further in implementing more conditions and to create few other columns in this regards. I highly appreciate all the help and for your valuable time.

Comment: Hi @MT0, I tried `close < LAG(open, 4) OVER (PARTITION BY stock ORDER BY close_date)` and was getting error "ORA-30483: window functions are not allowed here". So modified query to this and it worked. Thank you.
`bullish_harami AS 
      (PREV(close) - 3) < (PREV(open) - 3)
      and (PREV(close) - 2) < (PREV(open) - 2)
      and (PREV(close) - 1) < (PREV(open) - 1)
      and
      low > PREV(close)
      and
      high < PREV(open)
      and
      close > open,`

Comment: @Richa `PREV(close) - 3` takes the previous close value and subtracts 3 from it; it does not take the 3rd previous close value (which is what I think you are intending) as you would want `PREV(close, 3)` for that (where you specify that you want 3 rows offset rather than the default 1). Something like [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=abc7783d42b1e06a4f450e682a5fe737).

Comment: Thank you @MT0. I highly appreciate your help. May I know how to add one more computed column based on "PTTRN" values? I tried `case when pttrn = 'BULLISH_ENGULFING' then 'bullish' else 'bearish' end as flag ` but it is throwing error `ORA-00905: missing keyword`. Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Richa Your code works [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1d35231f27a8c2eca9a37e2281e29bb1).

Comment: Wow you are genius @MT0. You saved my day. Thank you again for quick help. I highly appreciate. You make it sound so simple. I was placing case statements inside define block and pattern. My bad. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 6):

I've upvoted @MT0's answer and I would use `match_recognize` for this sort of thing myself since this is squarely the sort of problem it is designed to deal with.  However, `match_recognize` is a pretty sophisticated construct and the patterns you're looking for are pretty simple.  So as expressed, you could solve your problem with a simpler query that just uses a few `lag` analytic functions.  As the patterns you're looking for get more sophisticated, you'll find that it'll be easier to express them using `match_recognize` and harder to handle them just with `lag` but the current problem is relatively easy to express this way.

Note that I'm making the same change to the "Piercing Line" formula that @MT0 did

```
with data as (
select src.stock,
       src.close_date,
       src.open o,
       src.close c,
       src.high h,
       src.low l,
       lag(src.open) over (partition by src.stock order by src.close_date) o1,
       lag(src.close) over (partition by src.stock order by src.close_date) c1,
       lag(src.high) over (partition by src.stock order by src.close_date) h1,
       lag(src.low) over (partition by src.stock order by src.close_date) l1
  from raw_source src
)
select d.*,
       case when o1 > c1 and c > o and c > h1 and o < l1
            then 'Bullish Engulfing'
            when (O1 < C1) and (O > C) and (O < C1) and (C > O1) and (H < H1) and (L > L1)
            then 'Bearish Harami'
            when (O < C) and (O1 > C1) and (C > (C1 + O1)/2) and (O < C1) and (C < O1)
            then 'Piercing Line'
         end pattern
  from data d
```

which produces the same results in the `pattern` column in [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=176a66ad1fac8729af819bd101b0e2f5).  Since we can use the same syntax you're using to express the formulas, though, it may be easier to follow the logic in this query than to understand the `match_recognize` syntax.

Comment: Thank you so much @JustinCave. I highly appreciate your time and help. Also thank you for the correction in OP. May I know if there's a way to figure out how many days did the stock was in downmove or upmove. For example as per the screenshot in OP, if today's date is 05/01/2021 (DD/MM/YYYY), is it possible to visualize or get the output saying trend was down for past 4 days?

Comment: @Richa - How do you define "down" or "up"?  Current close lower than prior day close?  Or something else?

Comment: Hi @JustinCave. That's very good question:
By using below query I get "Consecutive Days Count" which shows if the trend is in downmove based on the close price.
WITH StockRow AS (SELECT stock, close, close_date,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY stock 
ORDER BY close_date) rn
FROM raw_source),
RunGroup AS (SELECT Base.stock, Base.close_date,
MAX(Restart.rn) OVER(PARTITION BY Base.stock
ORDER BY Base.close_date) groupingId
FROM StockRow Base
LEFT JOIN StockRow Restart
ON Restart.stock = Base.stock
AND Restart.rn = Base.rn - 1
AND Restart.close > Base.close)..

Comment: ..SELECT stock, 
       COUNT(*) AS consecutiveCount, 
       MIN(close_date) AS startDate, MAX(close_date) AS endDate
FROM RunGroup
GROUP BY stock, groupingId
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
ORDER BY stock, startDate

Comment: Since there was character limit. Posted the query in two different comments. This is what I am trying to achieve i.e., first, to identify trend. Second, to identify candlestick pattern in combination with trend. As per the screenshot in OP