# How to apply a function to multiple values in parallel (in BigQuery)?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a long script but I'll include a part of it below and then explain the problem.

This code loops through combinations of `country` and `ngram` and process them to produce results.

> *Please note that you can ignore the code between the two `===XYZ===` marks. I included it in case it might help in the solution*.

```sql
DECLARE result ARRAY<STRUCT<country STRING, Metric STRING, consecutiveCount INT64, startDate TIMESTAMP, endDate TIMESTAMP>> DEFAULT [];

FOR record IN (select country, ngram from `dataset_1.table_11`)
DO
  set coun = record.country;
  set ng = record.ngram;
  SET result = ARRAY_CONCAT(result, ARRAY(SELECT struct(country, Metric, consecutiveCount, startDate, endDate) from (

  with term_t as
  (
    SELECT trending_at, country, ng as Metric, COUNTIF(CONTAINS_SUBSTR(LOWER(title), ng)) as Value 
    FROM `dataset_1.table_22` WHERE country = record.country GROUP BY 1,2
  ),

  -- ===XYZ===
  StockRow AS (SELECT Metric, Value, trending_at,
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Metric 
                                       ORDER BY trending_at) rn
              FROM term_t),

  RunGroup AS (SELECT Base.Metric, Base.trending_at,
                     MAX(Restart.rn) OVER(PARTITION BY Base.Metric
                                          ORDER BY Base.trending_at) groupingId
              FROM StockRow Base
              LEFT JOIN StockRow Restart
                     ON Restart.Metric = Base.Metric
                        AND Restart.rn = Base.rn - 1
                        AND Restart.Value >= Base.Value),
  
  F AS
  (
  SELECT Metric, 
         COUNT(*) AS consecutiveCount, 
         MIN(trending_at) AS startDate, MAX(trending_at) AS endDate
  FROM RunGroup
  GROUP BY Metric, groupingId
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
  ORDER BY Metric, startDate
  )
  
  -- ===XYZ===

  select coun as country, * from F)) );

END FOR;

INSERT INTO `dataset_1.table_33` SELECT * FROM UNNEST(result);
```

The problem with this code is that I have a lot of combinations of `country` and `ngram` to loop through, and this is taking a lot of time to finish.

A good solution for me would be if I didn't need to loop through the *ngrams* and instead replaced this:

```sql
  with term_t as
  (
    SELECT trending_at, country, ng as Metric, COUNTIF(CONTAINS_SUBSTR(LOWER(title), ng)) as Value 
    FROM `dataset_1.table_22` WHERE country = record.country GROUP BY 1,2
  )
```

with

```sql
  with term_t as
  (
    SELECT trending_at, country, ng_1 as Metric, COUNTIF(CONTAINS_SUBSTR(LOWER(title), ng_1)) as Value 
    FROM `dataset_1.table_22` WHERE country = record.country GROUP BY 1,2

  UNION ALL

  SELECT trending_at, country, ng_2 as Metric, COUNTIF(CONTAINS_SUBSTR(LOWER(title), ng_2)) as Value 
    FROM `dataset_1.table_22` WHERE country = record.country GROUP BY 1,2

  UNION ALL

  SELECT trending_at, country, ng_3 as Metric, COUNTIF(CONTAINS_SUBSTR(LOWER(title), ng_3)) as Value 
    FROM `dataset_1.table_22` WHERE country = record.country GROUP BY 1,2
  )

...
```

With this, I'd be able to loop through the countries only and process all country's ngrams (`ng_1`, `ng_2`, `ng_3`,...) in one loop iteration, which would reduce processing time and cost a lot. But I couldn't figure out how to do that. So I appreciate any help here.

---

**Edit:** Here are a sample data and the desired output:

`table_11`:

| country | ngram |
| --- | --- |
| US | lorem |
| US | ipsum |
| UK | ipsum |
| CA | dolor |
| CA | sit |

`table_22`:

| trending_at | country | title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-04 05:04:02 UTC | US | lorem ipsum xyz |
| 2021-03-05 20:04:02 UTC | US | dolor sit amet |
| 2021-03-05 05:04:02 UTC | US | lorem ipsum xyz |
| 2021-03-05 05:04:02 UTC | US | lorem xyz |
| 2021-03-06 05:04:02 UTC | US | wer lorem |
| 2021-03-06 05:04:02 UTC | US | plc lorem psl |
| 2021-03-06 05:04:02 UTC | US | uid asc |
| 2021-03-06 05:04:02 UTC | US | nic lorem max |
| 2021-03-05 20:04:02 UTC | UK | ipsum dolor sit amet |
| 2021-03-07 14:04:02 UTC | CA | dolor sit amet |
| 2021-03-08 17:04:02 UTC | CA | eiusmod tempor incididunt |
| 2021-03-09 17:04:02 UTC | CA | Duis aute irure |
| 2021-03-05 20:04:02 UTC | US | ullamco laboris nisi ut aliqui |

Desired output (written to `table_33`) based on the sample data above:

| country | Metric | consecutiveCount | startDate | endDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| US | lorem | 3 | 2021-03-04 05:04:02 UTC | 2021-03-06 05:04:02 UTC |

It contains only this record because "lorem" in US is the only one that had 3 or more consecutive increases (On 2021-03-04, it occurred in one title, on 2021-03-05, it occurred in two titles, and on 2021-03-06, it occurred in three titles)

Comment: Sample data and the disired output would help.

Comment: Can you please share some sample data and the desired output?

Comment: @Serg I added sample data and desired output.

Comment: @JoseGutierrezPaliza I added sample data and desired output.

Comment: you should add / describe logic you want to be implemented - from the example you provided  - i can try to derive it but better you describe it so "no shooting in the air"

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant What I want to achieve is this: Instead of running a query for each ngram for each country (inside the loop,) I want to run one query for all ngrams of each country. This would save a lot of time and cost. Please let me know if there are any details you want me to add. Thanks.

Comment: This is/was understood. What I asked is  - please explain in plain English the logic you are trying to implement - reverse engineering such logic from purely written sql usually does not end up with correct result. :o)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Got it. I have different video titles for each country and these videos were published on different days. I'm trying to find ngrams that were mentioned in those titles increasingly over time (i.e. if an ngram was mentioned in two titles on 2021-01-01, then in four titles on 2021-01-02, then in five titles on 2021-01-03, then this ngram meets the criteria because it achieved consecutive increases on 3+ consecutive days.


By the way, I'm using one of your answers to write to the result table once after the loop instead of multiple writes within the loops, so thanks for that.

Comment: Should it be at least three consecutive days? as an example - what if it will be 1 mentioning at first day, 2 at second, then none at third, but 4 at forth day?

Comment: The current implementation seeks 3+ consecutive days, so the case you mentioned would not meet the criteria. If it matters, the part that does that was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10356338/2282785) with a slight modification.

Comment: @AmmarAlyousfi One possible approach that I can think of is to join the `table_11` to a table with all the title tokens split out individually per row of data and then group them by day/token.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
with mentions_by_day as (
  select date(trending_at) date, t1.country, t1.ngram, count(1) counts
  from table_22 t2, unnest(split(lower(title), ' ')) t2_ngram
  join table_11 t1 on lower(t1.ngram) = t2_ngram and t1.country = t2.country
  group by country, ngram, date
), group_by_consecutive_dates as (
  select * 
    except(new_grp), countif(new_grp) over prev grp
  from (
    select *, 
      ifnull(lag(date) over prev + 1 != date, true) new_grp
    from mentions_by_day
    window prev as (partition by country, ngram order by date)
  )
  window prev as (partition by country, ngram order by date)
), group_by_consequtrive_growth as (
  select * except(new_grp), 
    countif(new_grp) over prev grp2
  from (
    select *, 
      ifnull(lag(counts) over(prev) >= counts, true) new_grp 
    from group_by_consecutive_dates
    window prev as (partition by country, ngram, grp order by date)
  )
  window prev as (partition by country, ngram, grp order by date)
)
select country, ngram as metric, 
  count(*) as consecutiveCount,
  min(date) as startDate,
  max(date) as endDate
from group_by_consequtrive_growth
group by country, metric, grp, grp2
having count(*) >= 3
```

if applied to sample data (table_11 and table_22) in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I realized, both grouping can be combined in one shot as in below example

```
with mentions_by_day as (
  select date(trending_at) date, t1.country, t1.ngram, count(1) counts
  from table_22 t2, unnest(split(lower(title), ' ')) t2_ngram
  join table_11 t1 on lower(t1.ngram) = t2_ngram and t1.country = t2.country
  group by country, ngram, date
), group_by_consequtive_date_growth as (
  select *, 
    countif(new_grp_by_consequtive_date) over prev grp_by_consequtive_date,
    countif(new_grp_by_consequtive_growth) over prev grp_by_consequtive_growth
  from (
    select *, 
      ifnull(lag(date) over prev + 1 != date, true) new_grp_by_consequtive_date,
      ifnull(lag(counts) over(prev) >= counts, true) new_grp_by_consequtive_growth
    from mentions_by_day
    window prev as (partition by country, ngram order by date)
  )
  window prev as (partition by country, ngram order by date)
)
select country, ngram as metric, 
  count(*) as consecutiveCount,
  min(date) as startDate,
  max(date) as endDate
from group_by_consequtive_date_growth
group by country, metric, grp_by_consequtive_date, grp_by_consequtive_growth
having count(*) >= 3
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I've tried it but found the results different that what the original code produced. I'm trying to figure out why this is happening.